# jQuery Field Not Being Removed After Appending it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running into an issue where I can't seem to get my jQuery script to remove fields after they have been added. I have tried a few changes, but nothing has worked.

```js
$(function() {
  var dataSourceField = $('#sign-up-organization-discovery-source');
  var i = $('#sign-up-organization-discovery-source p').size() + 1;

  $('#sign-up-add-discovery-source').on('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="discovery-source-field"><input type="text" id="discovery-source-field" size="20" name="discoverySource" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(dataSourceField);
    i++;
    return false;
  });
  $('#remScnt').on('click', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form action="/app/sign-up/organization" method="post">
      <p>{{user.email}}</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="{{user.email}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="organizationId">
      <label for="sign-up-organization">Company/Organization Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-organization" name="organizationName" value="" placeholder="Company/Organization">
      <a href="#" id="sign-up-add-discovery-source">Add Another Discovery Source</a>
      <div id="sign-up-organization-discovery-source">
        <input type="text" id="discovery-source-field" placeholder="Discovery Source" name="discoverySource">
      </div>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/login">Already have an account? Login here!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change `$('#remScnt').on('click', function() {`  use `$(document).on('click','#remScnt', function() { `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple problems here.

- Firstly, an `id` is suppose to be unique! You are duplicating `id` attribute values each time you append the element.
- Secondly, even if you were to use a class rather than an `id`, it still wouldn't work as expected because the clickable/removable `a` element doesn't exist in the DOM when you are attaching the event listeners.

You would either need to attach the event *after* appending the element, or you could use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and attach the event to a common parent element that exists at the time.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/L8kem0vy/)

```
$('#sign-up-organization-discovery-source').on('click', '.remove', function() {
   // ...
});
```

- I changed `<a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>` to: `<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>`.
- Then I [delegated](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the `click` event to the `#sign-up-organization-discovery-source` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('##sign-up-organization-discovery-source').on('click', '#remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: its better to add a few lines of explanation why you answer this and why his code didnt work